# Declaring CSS rules to apply only to a particular class

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS I need to apply to only a particular div (because of conflicts):

The div in question has the class name datepicker-days. Do I declare the below `table` as `.datepicker-days.table`? But then how do I declare the `.table` class below that?

**CSS**

```
    table {
      max-width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .table {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 18px;
    }
    .table th, .table td {
      padding: 8px;
      line-height: 18px;
      text-align: left;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block; ">
      <table class=" table-condensed">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th class="prev">
                ....
```

Sorry if this wasn't clear, the CSS rules are from Bootstrap. I'm just using a few of the rules because the datepicker plugin I am using depends on those particular rules. So where I have other instances of `<tables>` in my code, I don't want these rules to apply.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Also, avoid naming classes after elements, I'm getting confused between selectors for `<table>` and `class="table"`.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of how CSS class selectors work.  I would suggest [reading up on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_Reference#Selectors).  Otherwise I can't find the table class.

Comment: `datepicker-days.table` isn't a valid css rule. maybe you meant `.datepicker-days.table` ? That would be an element with both classes `.datepicker-days` and the **class** `.table`. You need the html tag `table` though. Go with @David's answer: `.datepicker-days table`

Comment: If you only need to apply CSS to a particular div, give it a unique id.

Comment: I wonder if he wants to style a `<div>` that has certain children. However there aren't any "parent-of" selectors in CSS that would allow for this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Please see edit at the bottom of question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the descendant selector:

```
.datepicker-days table {
    /* this rule will only apply to `<table>` elements that are descendents of any element with class "datepicker-days" */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.datepicker-days { /* Targets the div */ }

.datepicker-days table { /* targets all tables nested in the div */ }

.datepicker-days > table { /*targets only tables that are direct children on the div */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do the following:

```
.datepicker-days table {
    Styles here;
}
```

This looks for `<table>` with the `.datepicker-days` class only

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to apply a specific style to one unique div, why not give it an id #